# Residuals not normal due to random effects structure

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, residuals, mathematica

I am new to mixed-effect models and statistics, and I need to do a project for my thesis using mixed-effect modeling techniques.

My research aims to model how cardiovascular risk scores change over time. In this case, my mixed-effect model is

```
 lmer(log(Score) ~ Time + I(Time ^2) + (1+ Time + I(Time ^2) | Patients))
```

I have log transformed the score to improve the model fit. Quadratic function of time shows a better model fit. The random effect is allowing intercept and time to vary among patients.

I got an issue with the residuals of my best-fitted mixed-effect model. Q-Q plot shows the residuals are not normal on the individual level. However, the residuals look normal at the population level. If I fit a linear model (without the random effect component), the residuals also look normal. Hence, I suspected the issue was due to the random effect structure. I've been playing around with different random effect structures and correlations in the lme4 package in R, but neither could fix the residual issue.

I really need help to get through.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain what the data are and what questions you want to answer using the model?

Comment: If there is a dependence structure in your data that requires the mixed effects model, it is of no help and ultimately of no meaning that residuals of models that ignore this structure look more normal. From the given information I have no idea how harmful the non-normality you detected actually is. There's the robustlmm package in R that should give you fits that are less affected by non-normal tails.

Comment: Thanks. Please add this information to your question, not everyone reads comments.

Comment: FYI, You need a random slope on Time^2 if you are going to have one on Time.

Comment: yes, thanks, i have edited my post

Comment: You are treating `Score` as a continuous variable. Is that justified? Can you describe that variable in more detail? A quick check on the internet seems to indicate that some cardiovascular risk scores are actually percentages. That would suggest you should switch to a GLMM.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your reply, I understood the cardiovascular scores are percentages (ranging from 0 to 100 or 0 or 1 which is best fitted a beta distribution). However, I thought if I log transformed it, it will be approximately conform to normality? Thanks.

Comment: You might have thought so but the diagnostic plot shows that it is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Roland!

Answer (score 1):

it's a good call to see that you can look at residuals marginal (population-level) and conditional (on the RE).

The bad news here though is that what is relevant for your case are the conditional residuals, and they don't look normal. You shouldn't adjust the RE structure to correct this - it's not the fault of the REs, it can just happen that your residual error is non-normal.

In this case, you have at least 3 options to deal with distributional problem

- try other transformations
- beta regression
- quantile regressions

I would probably try if beta solves the problem (because this is the natural choice), and else try a quantile regression.

Additional comment: my personal opinion is that the (1+ Time + I(Time ^2) | Patients)) structure creates a weird setup for modelling between-patient variability in temporal trends, because of the dependency between Time and Time^2. I would prefer using factor smooths or factor smooth interactions, see e.g. [Multiply a seasonal spline by a region-specific coefficient in Generalized Additive Model (GAM) in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280359/multiply-a-seasonal-spline-by-a-region-specific-coefficient-in-generalized-addit). You can do so keeping your population-level estimate as a polynomial or move to a spline as well.

Comment: Hi, Florian, thank you kindly for the suggestion. I have tried log, logit, arcsine transformations, however, neither of these could solve the residual issue. I also tried to use the CVD score increase from the baseline instead of the raw CVD scores (both score-baseline & score/baseline then log transformed), it also didn't work. I suspected that's because the proportion data are usually skewed (my data is highly skewed to the left - most are distributed from 0.02-10%). Hence, it's difficult to solve the residual error by transformations?

Comment: I have tried GLMM with beta distribution, it works well so far. Compared with LMM, the result doesn't look very different, which is also good. Thanks for the suggestion for quantile regression, I haven't learned before, but I am willing to do some research

Comment: if a beta works, it's preferable because fully parametric, so I wouldn't change to quantile